# Force derived class to call base function in MATLAB?

Tags: oop, matlab, inheritance, virtual-functions

Base class has a function f.
Derived class overwrites the function f.
I want to call base class' f for an object of the derived class. How can I do this?

Here is the code sample.

```
    classdef base

        methods ( Access = public )
            function this = f( this )
                disp( 'at base::f' );
            end

        end
    end

    classdef derived < base

        methods ( Access = public )
            function this = f( this )
                % HERE I WANT TO CALL base::f
                this@base.f(); % this is an error

                disp( 'at derived::f' );
            end

        end
    end

d = derived();
d.f();
% here the result should be
% at base::f
% at derived::f
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

```
this@base.f();
```

it's

```
f@base(this)
```

Comment: @Vahagn: It will disp `at derived::f`, since that statement gets executed after the call to f@base. I don't understand the infinite loop, though.

Comment: @Vahagn: Here's the link in the documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/bsa1q42.html